# Python kivy [CRITICAL] [Clock ] Warning, too much iteration done before the next frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm making a calendar app in for mobile in kivy and wantto make a scrollview for a stack layout but keep getting this error and I don't know why

python code

`

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from calendar import monthrange
import calendar



year = 2022
month_int = 11
num_days = monthrange(year, month_int)[1]
weekheader = str(calendar.weekheader(3))
days = weekheader.split(" ")
days_length = len(days)
month = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month_int)
print(month)
start_day = month[0].count(0)
print(start_day)



class GridLayoutExample(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for l in range(2):
            label4 = Label()
            self.add_widget(label4)
        
        button2 = Button(text=str(month_int))
        self.add_widget(button2)
        button3 = Button(text=str(year))
        self.add_widget(button3)
        
        for k in range(3):
            label3 = Label()
            self.add_widget(label3)
        
        for j in range(days_length):
            label1 = Label(text=days[j], color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
            self.add_widget(label1)
        
        for g in range(start_day):
            label2 = Label()
            self.add_widget(label2)
        
        for i in range(num_days):
            button = Button(text=str(i + 1))
            button.my_id = str(i + 1) + "-" + str(month_int) + "-" + str(year)
            self.ids[str(i + 1) + "-" + str(month_int) + "-" + str(year)] = button
            self.add_widget(button)


class LayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for l in range(10):
            label4 = Label(text="zeer plezant \n \n \n ha \n haha", size = self.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 1), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.add_widget(label4)
            button = Button(text="verwijder")
            self.add_widget(button)
            button = Button(text="wijzig")
            self.add_widget(button)


class agenda1(MDApp):
    pass


agenda1().run()
```

`

kv file

```
#:kivy 1.0
PageLayoutExample:

<PageLayoutExample@PageLayout>:
    GridLayoutExample:
    ScrollViewExample:


<ScrollViewExample@ScrollView>:
    LayoutExample:
        



<GridLayoutExample>:
    #left-right  top-bottom
    cols: 7
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    size: root.minimum_width, root.minimum_height
    padding: ("20dp", "20dp", "20dp", "20dp")


<LayoutExample>:
    cols: 1
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    padding: ("20dp", "20dp", "20dp", "20dp")
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
```

Did I do something wrong in my code?

I want the scrollview to scroll as far as it has to to get all the data on the screen but not go any farther than that. because I iterate over an x amount task I don't really see a way to get less iterations in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `height: self.minimum_height` in your `LayoutExample`, you must provide definite sizes for its children.

The `Buttons` that you add to `LayoutExample` have the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`, so that causes an infinite loop in the `LayoutExample` layout calculations. It is trying to calculate its `minimum_height`, so each `Button` height gets set to the `LayoutExample` height, the `LayoutExample` then calculates and applies a new minimum height that will hold the `Buttons`. The `Buttons` then change their size to the new size of the `LayoutExample`, which triggers a new calculation by `LayoutExample` of its `minimum_height`....

The fix is just to specify a `size` for each `Button`, something like:

```
    for l in range(10):
        label4 = Label(text="zeer plezant \n \n \n ha \n haha", size=self.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 1),
                       size_hint=(None, None))
        self.add_widget(label4)
        button = Button(text="verwijder", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 20))
        self.add_widget(button)
        button = Button(text="wijzig", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 20))
        self.add_widget(button)
```

Comment: This works wonderfull, thank you! now the canvas for the full scrollview is working like I want it to because of the ability to set the height